# How does domain name preseeding work?

Tags: system-installation, dns, nginx, vps, nextcloud

I've just set up nextcloud according to this guide:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nextcloud-11-ubuntu-16-04-nginx-config

It's on a DigitalOcean VPS and I have the domain name dynamically allocated with a service called duckdns, so that I can reach my nginx webserver by simply typing:

`bitofagoob.duckdns.org`

Now, I understand how this part works. My VPS is running a script which informs duckdns of which IP address I'm at by pinging it every 10 minutes. When I want access to my VPS I just go via the duckdns service and I'm redirected to the relevant IP, even if it changes.

What I don't understand is how this is now working:

`nextcloud.bitofagoob.duckdns.org`

^this now gives me my new nextcloud server landing page.

How can a domain be transformed like this? If I think of a domain like this:

`bitofagoob@my.domain.com`

Then I am aware that I can control everything to the left of the '@' by adding new users/accounts etc, but how have I just been able to change something to the right of the '@'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're confused on what a domain name is. `bitofagoob@my.domain.com` is not a domain name; it's an email address (or maybe XMPP/Jabber address, or a bunch of other things that follow that format). It is made up of a local part (`bitofagoob`), a delimiter (`@`), and a fully-qualified domain name (`my.domain.com`).

A domain name is any name that's resolvable via DNS. A fully-qualified domain name is one that isn't omitting part of the suffix; e.g., you might be able to resolve `myhostname`, because your system knows to try adding `mydomain.com` to the end automatically. `myhostname.mydomain.com` is the fully-qualified domain name. Typically abbreviated FQDN. You can add a period at the end of the name to tell the local DNS resolver that is a FQDN and not to try adding any configured search suffixes.

DNS is organized into a hierarchy, starting from the *right* hand side of the FQDN. Each level decides who controls the next level down; you start at the right with the root domain (`.`) (controlled by ICANN); then get to `com.` (controlled by Verisign under contract with ICANN, and allowing open registration through many registrars). ICANN has decided that the registrant of a `com.` sub-domain (such as `domain.com.`) controls it.

So then the registrant of `domain.com.` has decided to make `my.domain.com.` work. They can create as many more levels as they want (within reason, I'm pretty sure DNS has a limit), and delegate control of those levels to whomever they desire (or keep control themselves).

The folks controlling duckdns.org set up a "wildcard" for you—they made `anything.bitofagoob.duckdns.org` resolve the same as `bitofagoob.duckdns.org`. (This is relatively easy to do with most DNS server software.)

Comment: Ah. So the way that domains are resolved is back to front, in this case starting with `com`, then `duckdns.com`, then `bitofagoob.duckdns.com`? By this stage, anything further to `bitofagoob.duckdns.com` is handled by my DDNS service and because they know the IP of my FQDN they then appended the `nextcloud` part on to end up with `nextcloud.bitofagoob.duckdns.com`?

Comment: To that end, if I started another webserver and called the landing page `mynewpage.bitofagoob.duckdns.com` but didn't enable it then the server at duckdns would still try and send me there if I typed it in my browser? This would result in a 404 until I started the service properly?

Comment: @bitofagoob yes, it'd resolve to your IP address. Whether your web server would send a 404 or not depends on the server config. (E.g., Apache is often configured with a default name vhost which it'll serve the request with).

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I now understand domain name resolution more properly.Will mark my question answered.